# HTTP 406 error server response: when sending filtering params in request

Tags: javascript, angularjs, asp.net-web-api, backend, backand

I have app in Backand that I'm building and I'm trying to use filter parameters. When calling my API using `$http` I get `406 error` in the http request.

This would be the API call, passing the filter object:

```
function getUserAttractions(userId) {

  return $http({

    method: 'GET',

    url: Backand.getApiUrl() + '/1/objects/attractions',

    params: {

      sort: [{
        "fieldName": "date",
        "order": "asc"
      }],

      filter: [{
        "fieldName": "user_id",
        "operand": "contains",
        "value": "1"
      }]

    }

  });

}
```

Comment: There is no enough information - 406 comes from backend. So just check backend code and logs - what is received and why backend responded with 406

Comment: I think you should should check your backend, and maybe show some of it's code (that API method that handles this requests).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, you should use "operator" instead of "operand".
If user_id is an object field then the filter should be:

```
filter: [{"fieldName":"user_id","operator":"in","value":"1"}]
```

here you can find additional documentation for other types of fields http://docs.backand.com/en/latest/apidocs/apidescription/index.html#rest-api-crud-operations

*Disclaimer: I work for Backand*

Answer (score 1):

With HTTP status 406 (Not Acceptable) the server is complaining that it cannot fulfill your request, probably because of your (missing) `Accept` header. See [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes#4xx_Client_Error).

I don't know what your server is supposed to send, so I'm assuming it should send JSON in a response.

Try the following:

```
return $http({
    method: 'GET',
    url: Backand.getApiUrl() + '/1/objects/attractions',
    headers: {
        'Accept': 'application/json, */*'
    },
    params: {
        sort: [{"fieldName":"date","order":"asc"}],
        filter: [{"fieldName":"user_id","operand":"contains","value":"1"}]
    }
});
```

See [AngularJS Page](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http) for more info.